# desktop file - Exec field - from where the arguments are taken?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, desktop-environments

The desktop files have a `Exec` field which can take arguments.

For example, the Nautilus desktop file has this line:

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
```

According to [the specs](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/), the field `%U` is:

> A list of URLs. Each URL is passed as a separate argument to the
> executable program. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs or
> as file path.

But from where these arguments/URLs are taken?
Who provides these argument?

When click on the Nautilus icon, there is no option to insert arguments.